# Implementation of draggable listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, drag-and-drop

I followed this tutorial for drag and drop listview implementation based on component that the Music app’s playlist uses.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australia/making-a-sortable-listview-in-android/708

Dragable listview works fine, but in the interface builder there is the error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.ib.myproject.TouchInterceptor (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

Here it is the part of the xml file:

```
<com.ib.myproject.TouchInterceptor
    android:id="@+id/listViewBankList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
</com.ib.myproject.TouchInterceptor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is telling you that the interface builder can't display anything as there is code logic which it can't resolve by itself.  In your custom view you can use `View.isInEditMode()` to declare code which will only be called by the interface builder.

So either in your view or the containing activity/fragment, you can define something such as:

```
if(View.isInEditMode()) {
  // some code which will help the view instantiate
}
```

Comment: which variables should i declare?

Comment: Should i write View.isInEditMode() in Activity which uses that unrecognized view?