# what is wrong in this main.xml?

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout

This is my main.xml

```
<com.example.parallax_sample xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.parallax_sample"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/teste" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Bottom"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Top"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.example.parallax_sample>
```

when I switch to graphical layout I see nothing (grey screen) ,with the exception stating.

Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup.

I may be wrong but it must be a problem of main.xml only .
How can i resolve it.

Here is the StackTrace

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parallax_sample/com.appkraft.parallax_sample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.example.parallax_sample
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.example.parallax_sample
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at com.appkraft.parallax_sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.parallax_sample" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.parallax_sample-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.parallax_sample-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
 E/AndroidRuntime(15768):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

Comment: don't need to worry if you run it will work

Comment: it does not ,app crashes.
looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"com.example.parallax_sample" is the problem, previews for custom view can't be created, though possibly it will work fine when you run it.

Comment: but it not working ,crashes at this point
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

from eclipse debug
any solution how to overcome that

Comment: have a look at the stack trace

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.parallax_sample" .. This is the problem, it cannot find the class. please make it sure that the class exists and it's accessible

Comment: I have noticed that but the package declaration is 

com.appkraft.parallax_sample
dont understand how come "example is coming"

Comment: yeah got it forgot to change in few files.

Answer (score 2):

Your root element on the xml is a custom element. If the graphical layout cannot render that first element, it won't be able to render the rest of them either.

Comment: so how can i fix my problem in this scenario ??

Comment: add the library to your workspace and add the project as a library :)\

Comment: @ Jlazar which library u r mentioning to add in the workspace

Comment: If this is an external library there probably is little you can do to make it render in the Graphical Editor. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423149/how-to-use-isineditmode-to-see-layout-with-custom-view-in-the-editor

Comment: kelmer ,I dont have that scenario ,
I dont have any null pointer exception,it is something just I am doing silly a newcomer hence can not locate that  
my log says that 

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.appkraft.parallax_sample 

and 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appkraft.parallax_sample" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.appkraft.parallax_sample-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.appkraft.parallax_sample-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 

any help on that

Comment: If your package declaration (as stated in the other answer) is `com.appkraft.parallax_sample`, then why are you using `com.example.parallax_sample`on your xml layout file?