# Google Play Services Sign in Button impossible to show in layout editor

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using the google Sign In button this way :

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In my app, at runtime, the button works like a charm, but in the Android Studio's layout editor, i have this error :

[image: The exception]

The library is properly imported through gradle, properly configured (the meta-data tags in the manifest are present), etc.

Is there a way to fix this ?

EDIT:

The same error occurs for every GPS views, in fact, even for my AdView, and i'm pretty sure that i used to be able to design it through the editor without any modification ...

Answer (score 0):

As your editor says **View.isInEditMode()**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423149/how-to-use-isineditmode-to-see-layout-with-custom-view-in-the-editor) post on how to do that. It suggests to use isInEditMode() in the constructor of the view. But as you are using google's **SignInButton** button the only way to achieve what you want(in my opinion not so sure) is to extend **SignInButton** button class and in its constructor override use **isInEditMode()**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to Java 7:

```
   compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
```