# Create custom view and display in Layout Preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-custom-view, preview

I've been creating custom views for a while now, but never got to make them in a way that the Android Studio preview displays them correctly.

I initialize the custom attributes using:

```
if (!isInEditMode()) {
...
}
```

But this results in an invisible component on preview.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 42):

You need to `rebuild` project. After that custom views in `preview` will work

Answer (score 4):

Have a look [here](https://medium.com/dualcores-studio/make-an-android-custom-view-publish-and-open-source-99a3d86df228#.jamvkxqud). I don't think you need to use that if statement. I never used it, and views always get displayed in previews

Comment: Thanks for the info, I use isInEditMode, because if I don't the preview displays an error suggesting to use that. So I'm not sure what stuff can be done or not in a view constructor in order to avoid these errors.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423149/how-to-use-isineditmode-to-see-layout-with-custom-view-in-the-editor) you might find a better answer

Answer (score 0):

When inflating your layout in your custom View clss, try with 
`attachToRoot` set to **true**.