# Using Picasso in XML object causes error in xml

Tags: android, xml, picasso, xml-visualizer

I am making an Avatar object which can be used in XML. When the object starts it is supposed to use picasso to get the users avatar image.  It looks like this

```
public class Avatar extends RoundedImageView {

private static String avatarURL;
private Context context;
public static List<Avatar> avatarList = new ArrayList<>();


public Avatar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public Avatar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public Avatar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init(){
    Avatar.avatarList.add(this);
    Picasso.with(context).load(avatarURL).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(this);
}
```

It works great however it makes the xml crash in view mode.  Is there a way to either make the xml ignore the Picasso line and just use a default image
or for the xml to be able to understand picasso.

Comment: Play around the `isInEditMode()` method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423149/how-to-use-isineditmode-to-see-layout-with-custom-view-in-the-editor

Comment: thanks that worked!